# Ways to cover up a hole in metal siding

Tags: hole, vinyl-siding

Any ideas how to cover up this hole in my siding? This hole is on the side of the house. Not sure what is was used for. Hopefully it’s something I can do myself.

[image]

Comment: Cover with sheet metal and paint or cut the hole and place a wooden plug, I say cut the hole because it looks out of round to me.

Comment: Do you have any scrap siding? Are you sure that's vinyl? Looks almost like cement board at the upper damage.

Comment: No scrap siding.. I think it’s metal. Sorry this is so new to me.. The scrap metal sounds good.. do I just attach it with nails then paint?

Comment: Depending how you care how it looks after, a patch will probably at best look like a patch.  Can patch it, but also cover it so it looks like a small door/flap or something similar.

Comment: @isherwood I'm pretty sure those cement board looking things at the top are blobs of caulk that are filling smaller (screw?) holes above.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the guidance, advice & suggestions. Joining this group has been wonderful

Answer (score 3):

1. Get yourself a bit of aluminum coil stock. Find a color that you can live with, or also pick up some spray paint in flat.
2. Cut a rectangular piece that's as wide as the damage plus 2", and as long as height of the siding face plus 2".
3. Using a scrap board with fairly sharp corners, bend the sheet so that it fits the profile of the siding. You want it to to cover the underside of the plank above the patch, the face with the damage, and the underside below the damage.  Trim length as needed.
4. Check your fit and the overall appearance, then drill into the underside planes for pop rivets or sheet metal screws. If needed, flex the patch so it lays well against the siding.
5. Paint the patch piece if necessary and let it dry well.
6. Apply a bead of silicone caulk around the top and sides of the damage (not below).
7. Press the patch in place and fasten it.

If you find that the width of the fastener area is too narrow for comfort, go ahead and rivet from the face four or six times. You could then make the patch just cover the face and underside below the damage. Put some caulk behind the rivet points to seal them.